# how to get access token via identityserver4 via method (not api)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, access-token, identityserver4

You can get a token by making a request for the token (as per example below).

But how do you get a (client credential) access token from within identityserver class (without requesting it via http POST web service api)? is there an identityserver4 method to use to obtain an access token?

---

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html

```
POST /connect/token

client_id=client1&
client_secret=secret&
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=hdh922&
redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/callback
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use the `IssueJwtAsync` or `IssueClientJwtAsync` methods from the `IdentityServerTools` class to do exactly that.

As per [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/tools.html).